# Struggling with recursion - function return an empty array when filtering an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have the following recursive function:

```
const findChildren = (id, array) => {
   const matchingItems = array.filter(arrayItem => {
       if (arrayItem.children) {
          findChildren(id, arrayItem.children)
       }
   
       return arrayItem.item.parent === id;
   })
     
   return matchingItems;
}
```

I am trying to find only the elements that have the same `parent` property equal to the `id` I'm passing in as an argument to the function. This is the array of objects I am working with:

```
const data = [
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "aaa"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "bbb",
          "parent": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "ccc",
          "parent": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "ddd"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "eee",
          "parent": 3
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "fff",
          "parent": 3
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 6,
              "name": "ggg",
              "parent": 5
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "hhh"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "iii",
          "parent": 7
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 9,
              "name": "jjj",
              "parent": 8
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 10,
                  "name": "kkk",
                  "parent": 9
                }
              },
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 11,
                  "name": "lll",
                  "parent": 9
                }
              },
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 12,
                  "name": "mmm",
                  "parent": 9
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 13,
              "name": "nnn",
              "parent": 8
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 14,
                  "name": "ooo",
                  "parent": 13
                }
              },
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 15,
                  "name": "ppp",
                  "parent": 13
                }
              },
              {
                "item": {
                  "id": 16,
                  "name": "qqq",
                  "parent": 13
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "rrr"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "sss",
          "parent": 17
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 19,
          "name": "ttt",
          "parent": 17
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 20,
              "name": "uuu",
              "parent": 19
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 21,
              "name": "vvv",
              "parent": 19
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 22,
          "name": "www",
          "parent": 17
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 23,
          "name": "xxx",
          "parent": 17
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 24,
              "name": "yyy",
              "parent": 23
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 25,
              "name": "zzz",
              "parent": 23
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When calling the function like so I get `undefined`:

```
console.log(findChildren(3, data));
```

I tried using `map` and `find`, the result is always `undefined`. I ran out if ideas and really struggle with recursion. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to handle recursion, I just used one method for example,

The problem you are having is that you are not adding the children result anywhere, you are just filtering it.

In the example below I use a side object to collect all the children results

```js
const data = [{
    "item": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "aaa"
    },
    "children": [{
        "item": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "bbb",
          "parent": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "ccc",
          "parent": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "ddd"
    },
    "children": [{
        "item": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "eee",
          "parent": 3
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "fff",
          "parent": 3
        },
        "children": [{
          "item": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "ggg",
            "parent": 5
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "hhh"
    },
    "children": [{
      "item": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "iii",
        "parent": 7
      },
      "children": [{
          "item": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "jjj",
            "parent": 8
          },
          "children": [{
              "item": {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "kkk",
                "parent": 9
              }
            },
            {
              "item": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "lll",
                "parent": 9
              }
            },
            {
              "item": {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "mmm",
                "parent": 9
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "item": {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "nnn",
            "parent": 8
          },
          "children": [{
              "item": {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "ooo",
                "parent": 13
              }
            },
            {
              "item": {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "ppp",
                "parent": 13
              }
            },
            {
              "item": {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "qqq",
                "parent": 13
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "rrr"
    },
    "children": [{
        "item": {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "sss",
          "parent": 17
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 19,
          "name": "ttt",
          "parent": 17
        },
        "children": [{
            "item": {
              "id": 20,
              "name": "uuu",
              "parent": 19
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 21,
              "name": "vvv",
              "parent": 19
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 22,
          "name": "www",
          "parent": 17
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "id": 23,
          "name": "xxx",
          "parent": 17
        },
        "children": [{
            "item": {
              "id": 24,
              "name": "yyy",
              "parent": 23
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": 25,
              "name": "zzz",
              "parent": 23
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const findChildren = (id, array) => {
  var matchingItems = [];
  const currentItems = array.filter(arrayItem => {

    if (arrayItem.children) {
      const childrenItems = findChildren(id, arrayItem.children);
      if (childrenItems.length > 0) {
        matchingItems.push(...childrenItems);
      }

    }

    return arrayItem.item.parent === id;

  })

  if (currentItems.length > 0) {
    matchingItems.push(currentItems);
  }
  return matchingItems;
}

console.log(findChildren(3, data));
```

Comment: thank you, it makes a lot of sense now since indeed, I wasn't adding the result anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would build this on top of a reusable function which traverses your `children`-branched objects collecting those that match a predicate.  It might look like this:

```js
const collect = (pred) => (xs = []) => 
  xs .flatMap (x => [
    ... (pred (x) ? [x] : []),
    ... collect (pred) (x .children)
  ])

const findChildren = (id, data) => 
  collect (({item: {parent}}) => parent == id) (data)

const data = [{item: {id: 0, name: "aaa"}, children: [{item: {id: 1, name: "bbb", parent: 0}}, {item: {id: 2, name: "ccc", parent: 0}}]}, {item: {id: 3, name: "ddd"}, children: [{item: {id: 4, name: "eee", parent: 3}}, {item: {id: 5, name: "fff", parent: 3}, children: [{item: {id: 6, name: "ggg", parent: 5}}]}]}, {item: {id: 7, name: "hhh"}, children: [{item: {id: 8, name: "iii", parent: 7}, children: [{item: {id: 9, name: "jjj", parent: 8}, children: [{item: {id: 10, name: "kkk", parent: 9}}, {item: {id: 11, name: "lll", parent: 9}}, {item: {id: 12, name: "mmm", parent: 9}}]}, {item: {id: 13, name: "nnn", parent: 8}, children: [{item: {id: 14, name: "ooo", parent: 13}}, {item: {id: 15, name: "ppp", parent: 13}}, {item: {id: 16, name: "qqq", parent: 13}}]}]}]}, {item: {id: 17, name: "rrr"}, children: [{item: {id: 18, name: "sss", parent: 17}}, {item: {id: 19, name: "ttt", parent: 17}, children: [{item: {id: 20, name: "uuu", parent: 19}}, {item: {id: 21, name: "vvv", parent: 19}}]}, {item: {id: 22, name: "www", parent: 17}}, {item: {id: 23, name: "xxx", parent: 17}, children: [{item: {id: 24, name: "yyy", parent: 23}}, {item: {id: 25, name: "zzz", parent: 23}}]}]}]

console .log (findChildren (3, data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`collect`** takes an arbitrary predicate and returns a function.  That function takes an array of objects with recursively nested `children` arrays and returns all those elements which match the predicate.

Then **`findChildren`** passes `collect` a simple predicate testing your parent id condition, and passes the list of objects to the generated function.

There's a slight variant of this that I prefer:

```js
const findChildren = (id) => 
  collect (({item: {parent}}) => parent == id)

findChildren (3) (data)
```

This allows you to store the partially applied function, `findChildren (3)` to use against multiple objects.  While that might not be necessary for your case, it adds a nice flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ item: { id: 0, name: 'aaa' }, children: [{ item: { id: 1, name: 'bbb', parent: 0 } }, { item: { id: 2, name: 'ccc', parent: 0 } }] }, { item: { id: 3, name: 'ddd' }, children: [{ item: { id: 4, name: 'eee', parent: 3 } }, { item: { id: 5, name: 'fff', parent: 3 }, children: [{ item: { id: 6, name: 'ggg', parent: 5 } }] }] }, { item: { id: 7, name: 'hhh' }, children: [{ item: { id: 8, name: 'iii', parent: 7 }, children: [{ item: { id: 9, name: 'jjj', parent: 8 }, children: [{ item: { id: 10, name: 'kkk', parent: 9 } }, { item: { id: 11, name: 'lll', parent: 9 } }, { item: { id: 12, name: 'mmm', parent: 9 } }] }, { item: { id: 13, name: 'nnn', parent: 8 }, children: [{ item: { id: 14, name: 'ooo', parent: 13 } }, { item: { id: 15, name: 'ppp', parent: 13 } }, { item: { id: 16, name: 'qqq', parent: 13 } }] }] }] }, { item: { id: 17, name: 'rrr' }, children: [{ item: { id: 18, name: 'sss', parent: 17 } }, { item: { id: 19, name: 'ttt', parent: 17 }, children: [{ item: { id: 20, name: 'uuu', parent: 19 } }, { item: { id: 21, name: 'vvv', parent: 19 } }] }, { item: { id: 22, name: 'www', parent: 17 } }, { item: { id: 23, name: 'xxx', parent: 17 }, children: [{ item: { id: 24, name: 'yyy', parent: 23 } }, { item: { id: 25, name: 'zzz', parent: 23 } }] }] }];

const find = objectScan(['**(^children$).item.parent'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'gparent',
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ value, context }) => value === context
});

console.log(find(data, 3));
// => [ { item: { id: 4, name: 'eee', parent: 3 } }, { item: { id: 5, name: 'fff', parent: 3 }, children: [ { item: { id: 6, name: 'ggg', parent: 5 } } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)